# What permissions / ownership to set on PHP Sessions Folder when running FastCGI / PHP-FPM (as user "nobody")?

Tags: linux, security, php, centos

I'm having trouble getting a number of scripts running because PHP-FPM can't write to my session folder:

```
"2009/10/01 23:54:07 [error] 17830#0: *24 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP Warning:
    Unknown: open(/var/lib/php/session/sess_cskfq4godj4ka2a637i5lq41o5, O_RDWR)
    failed: Permission denied (13) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Unknown: Failed to write session data (files). Please verify
    that the current setting of session.save_path is correct
    (/var/lib/php/session) in Unknown on line 0" while reading upstream"
```

Obviously this is a permission issue; my session folder's owner/group is the webserver's user, NGINX. PHP-FPM runs as `nobody` though, and hence adding it to the nginx group is not so trivial.

A temporary solution is to set the permissions of `/var/lib/php/session` to `777` - I have a feeling that's not the "best practice" though.

What is the best practice when you need to assign a daemon write access to a folder, but it is running as `nobody` ?

Answer (score 26):

The correct permissions for us where

```
chown -R nobody:nogroup /var/lib/php/session
```

as `php-cgi` runs as `nobody`, even though NGinx runs as user `nginx`

Comment: In my case it wasn't a question of ownership/permissions. Remove the "3;" from session.save_path = "3;/var/lib/php/sessions"

Comment: I get the following error: Invalid group <<nobody:nogroup>>  :(

Comment: i was able to see which is my `nobody` user that runs php with this line of code: `<?php echo exec('whoami'); ?>` (in my case www-data) and after that it was simple as just wrote `chown -R www-data:www-data /var/lib/php/sessions` this is an underrated google result as it was the only answer that it helped me after hours of searching! thanks!

Answer (score 10):

If you use **nginx** you might run into this when running a system update.

Sometimes when you update the system, the group of `/var/lib/php/session` is changed to apache.

Try executing `sudo chgrp nginx /var/lib/php/*` instead of setting permissions to 777 which is a bad practice.

That worked for me at least.

Answer (score 3):

Use `/etc/php.ini` [session.save_path](https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.save-path) directive.

> A temporary solution is to set the
> permissions of /var/lib/php/session to
> 777 - I have a feeling that's not the
> "best practice" though.

"If you leave this set to a world-readable directory, other users on the server may be able to hijack sessions by getting the list of files in that directory. "

Comment: Sorry I think I may not have been clear:
session.save_path is already set to /var/lib/php/session . The problem is I can't figure out what permissions and ownership to assign to the session path directory in order to both enable PHP-FPM to write to it, as well as keep it safe.

Having the directory set as owner/group "nginx"(The web server I'm running) and permissions 755 doesn't seem to do the trick

Comment: 1. Use same user:group for nginx and php-fpm (via either `nginx.conf` or `php-fpm.conf`), so you can keep this directory 700.  
2. Use `chown -R nginx:nobody /var/lib/php/session && chmod -R 770 /var/lib/php/session` so i think both nginx and php-fpm can use it

Comment: I can confirm that using nginx:nobody (or nginx:nogroup in some circumstances) works. If it is possible, I'd lean towards SaveTheRbtz' option 1, though.

Answer (score 3):

I had to create folder with 0700 rights in /var/lib/php/session for each php-fpm pool.

Owner of this folder is user and group from php-fpm pool.

And /var/lib/php/session now 0777.

I think this method is most secure. 
Only php-fpm pool user will see this sessions.

Answer (score 2):

The correct way should be changing the ownership of the session folder to nginx.
However, PHP-FPM does not run using the nginx user by default. It uses apache by default.

With that said, you must change the user that's used by PHP-FPM by editing `/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf`.

```
; Unix user/group of processes
; Note: The user is mandatory. If the group is not set, the default user's group
;       will be used.
; RPM: apache Choosed to be able to access some dir as httpd
user = nginx
; RPM: Keep a group allowed to write in log dir.
group = nginx
```

Restart PHP-FPM and you should be good to go.

`service php-fpm restart`

---

PHP session path location can be found in `/etc/php.ini` under `session.save_path`. `/var/lib/php/session` is the default.

Command to update ownership and group of php session folder

`chown -R nginx:nginx /var/lib/php/session`

And you should be good to go even with chmod of `700`.

Answer (score 2):

Directory /var/lib/php/sessions should have sticky bit permissions.

```
sudo chmod 1773 /var/lib/php/sessions

ls -al /var/lib/php/
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root   .
drwxr-xr-x 51 root root   ..
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root   modules
drwx-wx-wt  2 root root   sessions
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I solved it. I went to `/tmp` (that's where my ses_* files are) and deleted them all. After that everything was OK.

As nears as I could tell the system was trying to write on old locked files.

The problem occured after I was playing with `php.ini`. I lost a couple years from my life but eventually I found the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Based on **@Judder** answer, to make it work i had to add the following command to give **read** and **write** permissions to **nobody** and **nogroup**:

`chown -R nobody:nogroup /var/lib/php/session`

`sudo chmod -R ug+rw /var/lib/php/sessions`

**chmod** will change the permissions on the given folder

**-R** will apply the same permissions to the folders and files created within the given folder

**u** for user

**g** for group

**r** for read permission

**w** for write permission

Answer (score 0):

I'm running Apache and Nginx Reverse Proxy Server and I experienced this same issue. This is what I did to resolve the errors.

```
chown -R apache:nobody /var/lib/php/*
chmod g+w /var/lib/php/session
```

Hope this helps someone with the same problem.